# Watir::Wait.until not working with frames

Tags: watir

I'm automating an internal tool that is rife with frames, using Watir.  I am able to manipulate all the various elements so I know I am identifying the frames correctly, but any time I attempt to use a Wait statement for any of these elements it fails.  Tracking back through the error message, it always hits the activesupport gem in core_ext/time/calculations and it looks like it can't get the duration value, it gets set to false, and then the operation fails because it is expecting a Float.  Is this a bug?

Using Ruby 1.8.7 and Watir 1.6.7

My code is:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'watir/testcase'
require 'main_setup'
require 'win32ole'
require 'common'

class Smoketest < Watir::TestCase
  include CommonCode
  def test_AddEdit_Endpoint
    Watir::Wait.until { @b.link(:id,"lbShowEndpointForm").exists? }
  end
end
```

Error is the following:

```
test_basic_smoke(Smoketest):
TypeError: can't convert false into Float
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:278:in `plus_without_duration'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.9/lib/active_support/core_ext/time/calculations.rb:278:in `+'
    C:/Ruby187/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/commonwatir-1.6.7/lib/watir/wait.rb:15:in `until'
    C:/qa/trunk/CCAdmin/Automation/CCAdmin/lib/smoketest.rb:27:in `test_basic_smoke'
```

Comment: require 'rubygems'
require 'watir/testcase'
require 'main_setup'
require 'win32ole'
require 'common'

class Smoketest <Watir::TestCase
  include CommonCode

  def test_AddEdit_Endpoint
     
    Watir::Wait.until{@b.link(:id,"lbShowEndpointForm").exists?}

Comment: sorry, missing the end/end.  I was also going to mention the browser variable @b is created in the CommonCode module.  Literally, all I was doing was opening a browser window and using a wait statement for an element.

Comment: looks like you do not know you can edit your question. Let me do that for you.

Comment: Thank you Željko.  In response to Jarmo below, the original error message was from the full test code including many variable instantiations that do nothing to the error, confirmed by running the briefer snippet above and getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

So, which line is the C:/qa/trunk/CCAdmin/Automation/CCAdmin/lib/smoketest.rb:27?

Comment: you should delete this as an answer and add it as a comment

Answer (score 0):

I thought the correct usage for the command was wait_until, unless it's changes from Watir 1.6.5, http://wtr.rubyforge.org/rdoc/1.6.5/classes/Watir/Waiter.html